# setIcon not working when using it for a JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel, imageicon

When I set the background color to `null`, using `setIcon` is not working, although `setText` still works. What's the reason for this, and how can I fix it?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==arrowr){
        Reset();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("queen.bmp");
        b[1][1].setBackground(null);
        b[1][1].setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the size, type and expected appearance of the icon? Have you verified that it does show up with the background color is not `null`? This could be caused by the fact that [the constructor you are using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29) does not throw an exception on missing file.

Comment: size is same as that of the button

Comment: no it doesn't show up when the background color is not null

Comment: Then there is a 99% chance that you are not loading the icon at all.

Comment: Show a directory listing of the folder from which you are running the code.

Comment: Convert the image to .png: `queen.png`. The .bmp format is not supported out-of-the-box.